# How to check if Doctrine 1.2 sqlite cache is working?

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to set up doctrine sqlite cache in Symfony 1.4 with following code:

```php
$cacheConn   = Doctrine_Manager::connection( new PDO( 'sqlite::memory:' ) );
$cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Db( array( 'connection' => $cacheConn, 'tableName' => 'cache' ) );
$cacheDriver->createTable();
$manager->setAttribute( Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, $cacheDriver );
$manager->setAttribute( Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE, $cacheDriver );
$manager->setAttribute( Doctrine_Core::ATTR_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 60 * 5 );
$manager->setAttribute( Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 60 * 5 );
```

I don't see any errors, but script execution time stays exactly the same as without cache. How to check that cache is actually working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have persistency between requests.

To make your sqlite::memory valid for the next request(s) you must use "persistency"

> In memory sqlite has some limitations. The memory space could be the request, the session, but no way seems documented to share a base in memory among users.
>
> For a request, open your base with the code
>   $pdo = new PDO( 'sqlite::memory:');
>   and your base will disapear on next request.
>
> For session persistency :
>
> `$pdo = new PDO(
>           'sqlite::memory:',
>           null,
>           null,
>           array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
>       );`

Source : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php

Copy & Paste from comment of [frederic dot glorieux at diple dot net]